# .net core web api http post null model in some cases

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have two controllers. One for **categories** and one for **fields**.
In both controllers I have a post method, the **categories** one works fine. The **fields** one always has a null model.

Both controllers are decorated with:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
```

The **categories** method looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new category
/// </summary>
/// <param name="category">The category</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Category), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(CategoryViewModel category)
{
    if (category == null) return BadRequest();
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

    var request = ModelFactory.Create(category);

    _categoryService.Create(request);
    await _categoryService.SaveChangesAsync();

    request.Fields = new List<Field>
    {
        new Field {CategoryId = request.Id, DataType = FieldDataType.Text, Name = "gtin"},
        new Field {CategoryId = request.Id, DataType = FieldDataType.Text, Name = "title"},
        new Field {CategoryId = request.Id, DataType = FieldDataType.Text, Name = "retailer"},
        new Field {CategoryId = request.Id, DataType = FieldDataType.Text, Name = "url"},
        new Field {CategoryId = request.Id, DataType = FieldDataType.Text, Name = "imageUrl"},
        new Field {CategoryId = request.Id, DataType = FieldDataType.Text, Name = "currency"},
        new Field {CategoryId = request.Id, DataType = FieldDataType.Double, Name = "price"}
    };

    foreach (var field in request.Fields)
        _fieldService.Create(field);

    await _fieldService.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Created(nameof(Get), new Sxp.Web.ActionResult<Category>(request, string.Format(Resources.EntityCreated, "category")));
}
```

I can use postman to send a request and it works fine:

[image]

My **fields** endpoint looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new field
/// </summary>
/// <param name="field">The field</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Field), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(FieldViewModel field)
{
    if (field == null) return BadRequest();
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

    var request = ModelFactory.Create(field);

    _fieldService.Create(request);
    await _fieldService.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Created(nameof(Get), new Sxp.Web.ActionResult<Field>(request, string.Format(Resources.EntityCreated, "field")));
}
```

When I send a request to this endpoint, the model is always null.
The request looks like this:

[image]

The requests seem to be the same, but for some reason the **field** is null when I try to create one.
I have tried using the `[FromBody]` attribute, but it is still null.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: show us the FieldViewModel class code please?

Comment: You forgot a comma after "id": 0 and after "dataType": 2.

Comment: And a comma after "dataType": 2 as well

Comment: Postman is already telling you that your JSON is malformed, there's a red cross you have ignored.

Comment: doh! I didn't even see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put comma after `"id":0` and `"dataType": 2` at the body of your request. When json is not valid model is evaluated null

Comment: and a comma after "dataType": 2 as well :)

Comment: @AzharKhorasany nice catch also =)

Comment: Generally we vote to close questions that are just typos.

Comment: @DavidG oh my bad. Should I remove my answer then?

Comment: @DavidG thank you for the advice. I will definitely keep that in mind, Happy coding!